# ArcMap Cell calculations and focal statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics

I have a raster with gridsize 10m x 10m. Cells have values 1 or 2. For every raster cell I want to make a calculation using cells in a 200 cell (2000 m) radius. I want to find out the percentage of cells with value 1 within this radius. The calculation should be

"Number of cells within 200 cell radius" / "Number of cells with value 1".

I tried focal statistics and zonal statistics, but I can't find the option to input my equation.
Am I looking at the wrong tools?

Answer (score 1):

This is a large radius, so this will be computationnally expensive. That being said, focal stat is the good tools if you have only 1 and 2 values: make the sum of the cells with focal stat, then

"percentage of cells == 1" is equal to 100*(2*(number of cells in the radius)-(focal stat result))/(number of cells in the radius)